# How change vehicle color

Tags: omnet++, veins

How can I change the veins vehicle icon color according to its function?

In the tictoc 2 example, this was possible by changing @display ("i =, cyan") from your ned file.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines at the beginning of your application code:

```
#define black TraCIColor(0,0,0,0)
#define red TraCIColor(255,0,0,0)
#define green TraCIColor(0,255,0,0)
#define yellow TraCIColor(255,255,0,0)
#define blue TraCIColor(0,0,255,0)
#define violet TraCIColor(255,0,255,0)
#define cyan TraCIColor(0,255,255,0)
#define white TraCIColor(255,255,255,0)
```

Then, to set the color to green of car with number carId, add to your code the following lines:

```
self = getParentModule()->getIndex();
traciVehicle = mobility->getVehicleCommandInterface();
if(self==carId) traciVehicle->setColor(green);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will make this configuration and then return to you.

Comment: For avoid errors I put the line #include "veins / modules / mobility / traci / TraCIColor.h"

However the following errors are displayed:

`self` was not declared in this scope
`carId` was not declared in this scope

Comment: Open the application file .h and add: int self. carId is just a numerical identification (integer) of the car you intend to change the color. Every car has a numerical identification that you can know it by printing the respective self value: cout << self << endl;

Comment: Even setting the variable didn't work. is it necessary to define carId too?

Comment: In my case, I was able to solve the problem by copying the default veins image folder to the OMNET ++ images folder. So I defined the line: findHost()->getDisplayString().updateWith("r=16,red;i=node/car,gold");. That way, every time an accident occurs, the crashed car changes color and sends a message. This was the test I did, later I want to define the member car, CH and gateway of a cluster with different colors.